# Adding two numbers from the database in the Spring Service layer

Tags: java, spring

I have an entity called User which holds three fields:

ID No1

1   5

2   4

Then I have a UserRepository which extends JpaRepository, thus including crud operations.
I want to be able to take value 5 and 4 and add them together.
This logic should be applied in the Service layer.
So I have a `AddService` interface and `AddServiceImpl` which implements that interface.

```
public interface AddService{
    public void addNumbers(user1, user2);
}

public class AddServiceImpl implements AddService{
     public void addNumbers(user1, user2){
            List<User> user1=userRepository.findOne(1);
            List<User> user2=userRepository.findOne(2);
     // how do I take those specific values that are on the field No?
 }
}
```

How do I implement this Service so that it adds those numbers?
I need to inject the repository and save a list with the data from user1 and user2 and then add them? But how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

try this code and let me know if this what you want

```
public Integer addNumbers(user1, user2){
    List<User> user1=userRepository.findOne(1);
    List<User> user2=userRepository.findOne(2);
    Integer number1 = user1.getNo();
    Integer number2 = user2.getNo();
    return number1 + number2;
}
```

If the user1.getNo() or if user2.getNo() could be null please take car of this as well. I do not know in this case what you want to return.

In addition ,change the interface to return an Integer

```
public interface AddService{
    public Integer addNumbers(user1, user2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

user1.getID() and user1.getNo() without the user class it’s hard to tell. Same thing for user2. Could you provide User for us?

findOne shouldn’t have a list in return type. It should be unique.

The calls to the repository shouldn’t be in your addNumbers method because your users are in the method parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a list of type User ? Anyway, what you should do is iterate over the list and for each User object in your list get the numbers using the getter of that field. You must have the getters and setters for all the fields on your entity class, this way you can get the value of your instance variables on your repository class.